# Best way to mark up a countdown timer

Tags: html, semantics

I am trying to achieve something similar to what is shown on the following page:

http://2.s3.envato.com/files/7689014/index.html

Basically a countdown timer.

I am a little unsure semantically what is the best way to mark this up.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Semantic on page load, or semantic in the DOM? There's a difference.

Comment: I suppose both would be good. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Semantics (as far as I'm concerned) only matters as far as the page source that the browser loads. What happens to the page after it's parsed and becomes part of the DOM, semantics become less meaningful, since the page is no longer in a state that is parsable. The former, source semantics, gives the data the page contains meaning, the latter, you're simply manipulating instance data.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking that. SO do I have an empty div then populate it? Or should I have a meaningful mark up in there to start with?

Comment: Is there some kind of meaningful longevity you're exploring with your timer markup? Why not just a `DIV` with the initial date/timestamp?

Comment: Just trying to think of accessibility and screen readers.

Comment: Just wondering, how do you test for accessibility?

Comment: There are a number of manual and automated tools you can use, here is one:

http://www.totalvalidator.com/home/eol.html

Comment: But you don't do a simulated live (or real) JAWS session or anything?

Comment: Note, also, that the link you provided to totalvalidator.com is no longer in service. `:(`

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you could either use microformats, or the html 5 `time` element:

```
<time date="2011-10-31">2011-10-31</time>
```

Possibly with the `pubdate` (Boolean) attribute to define the time as the publication date:

```
<time date="2011-10-31" pubdate>
```

You may need to wrap the individual components in `span`s, perhaps, to allow for styling each day, hour, minute, second...as an individual counter, though:

```
<time date="2011-10-31" pubdate><span class="year">2011</span>-<span class="month">11</span>-<span class="day">31</span></time>
```

References:

- [`<time>` at html5doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com/the-time-element/).
- [`<time>` at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/time).
- ['Making `<time>` safe for Historians', at Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/04/making_time_saf.html).

Comment: Do you have a good resource link for understanding the full HTML5 element library?

Comment: Do you mean the full resources available under html5? If so...then there's [HTML5Doctor.com](http://html5doctor.com/). And, following that, I'd recommend browsing [HTML5 elements at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5); and, of course, looking for the same elements at the [W3.org](http://w3.org/).

Comment: @David Has time not recently been depricated?

Comment: Not that I know of; but it's more than possible. Do you have a link to a source for that supposition..?